# Search for text in webpage, if not found skip to next word

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am working with a vba to search for a text from excel in a website. The problem is that the website don't have any source code to directly search there so I was using sendkeys for searching.

Is there any alternate to search without sourcecode as I cant skip the condition of search if the text is not found in the webpage.
I want the code to skip to next word if the text is not found in the webpage.

Below is the code:

```
   With iedoc.forms(0)
    ActiveSheet.Range("H5").Copy
SendKeys "^f", True
SendKeys "^v", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
SendKeys "^{ }", True
ActiveSheet.Range("H6").Copy
SendKeys "^f", True
SendKeys "^v", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
SendKeys "^{ }", True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the text with (assuming `iedoc` is defined as the IE Document anyway)

```
sText = iedoc.Body.Innertext ' get all the text from the browser
```

Then you have it in memory and can check words against it with `InStr` as you like?

For example, to check the value of Cell "H5", you can do the following:

```
If (Instr(sText, ActiveSheet.Range("H5").Value)>0 Then
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("H5").Value & " was found in the text!"
End If
```

I would recommend not using `ActiveSheet` though as it can change easily depending on the worksheet that's active at the time and your code can be looking at the wrong tab.  Always better to define which worksheet you are looking at and reference it directly:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet : Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheetNameHere")
```

Then you can be sure your code will always reference the sheet you wanted it to with:

```
If (Instr(sText, ws.Range("H5").Value)>0 Then
    MsgBox ws.Range("H5").Value & " was found in the text!"
End If
```

Comment: It will be a great help if u can help me in replacing the suggested answer with my code.